# How to allow custom return types of member functions for type erasure in C++?

Tags: c++, type-erasure

Over the last years, **type erasure** or **concept-based runtime polymorphism** became quite popular, see e.g. the talks by **Sean Parent** [Better Code: Runtime Polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg), [Inheritance Is The Base Class of Evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIhUE5uUFOA) or [C++ Seasoning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA) resp. the implementations by [Adobe](http://stlab.adobe.com/group__poly__related.html), [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Poly.md), [Boost.TypeErasure](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html), [Boost.te](https://github.com/boost-experimental/te) or [dyno](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno).

Here is an example from Sean Parent's talk:

```
class object_t {
    struct concept_t {
        virtual ~concept_t() = default;
        virtual void draw_(ostream&, size_t) const = 0;
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct model final : concept_t {
        model(T x) : data_(move(x)) { }
        void draw_(ostream& out, size_t position) const override 
        { draw(data_, out, position); }
        T data_;
    };
    shared_ptr<const concept_t> self_;
public:
    template <typename T>
    object_t(T x) : self_(make_shared<model<T>>(move(x))){ }
    friend void draw(const object_t& x, ostream& out, size_t position)
    { x.self_->draw_(out, position); }    
};
```

In the example above any class `T` has to provide a function

```
void draw(T data, std::ostream out, size_t position);
```

which is simple to achieve for any `T` since the return type is `void` and the arguments signatures are all known a compile time. Same would be true, if the return type would by int, double, std::string etc.

Here is the actual question: **How to do this for a custom return type `RType` resp. argument type `ArgType`?**

```
class object_t {
    struct concept_t {
        virtual ~concept_t() = default;
        virtual void draw_(ostream&, size_t) const = 0;
        virtual RType foo (ArgType arg) const = 0; // new function
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct model final : concept_t {
        model(T x) : data_(move(x)) { }
        void draw_(ostream& out, size_t position) const override 
        { draw(data_, out, position); }
        RType foo (ArgType arg) const override 
        { return data_.foo(arg);}; // new function
        T data_;
    };
    shared_ptr<const concept_t> self_;
public:
    template <typename T>
    object_t(T x) : self_(make_shared<model<T>>(move(x))){ }
    friend void draw(const object_t& x, ostream& out, size_t position)
    { x.self_->draw_(out, position); }    
    RType foo (ArgType arg) const 
    { return self_->foo(arg);}; // new function
};
```

(i) If `RType` or `ArgType` would be an explicit type, i.e. there exists a type `class MyClass{};` we could define `using RType = MyClass;` or `using ArgType = MyClass` and everything is fine.

(ii) If `RType` or `ArgType` would be a concept-based polymorphic type such as `object_t` it is also fine. *But this would mean that the codebase would be full of interface classes such as `object_t`. Don't get me wrong this would be a fair price to pay, but it will take some time to get used to it and structure a codebase to do so.*

**Now the problematic part: Can I make the example work if I have something like this `using RType = typename T::RType` or `using ArgType = typename T::ArgType` for a class `T`???**

I.e.

```
class T {
public:
    using ArgType = /*...*/;
    using RType = /*...*/;
/*...*/
};
```

**Edit:**

The final goal is to have two classes

```
class MyClass {
    using ArgType = /* e.g. int*/; 
    using RType = /* e.g. double*/;
    RType foo (ArgType arg) const {/*...*/;}
};
```

and

```
class YourClass {
    using ArgType = /* e.g. size_t*/; 
    using RType = /* e.g. float*/;
    RType foo (ArgType arg) const {/*...*/;}
};
```

such that we can use both with `object_t`, i.e.

```
object_t myObj(MyClass(/*...*/));
object_t yourObj(YourClass(/*...*/));
// use provided functionality
// ... myObj.foo(...)
// ... yourObj.foo(...)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here. Do you want to have `object_t::draw` return different values based on what parameter it is given? Do you want every `T` given to an `object_t` to be able to take *any* `ArgType`, or do you want each `T` to be able to map a specific `ArgType` to a specific `RType`? If the latter is the case, do you want `object_t` to be a template on `ArgType`, or do you expect `object_t::draw` to force the contained object to be able to take any `ArgType`?

Comment: You can't without using (ii), or using the flexibility offered by the covariant return type rule.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry this was not clear to me. For now, any version would be fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas I edit the question. I hope the issue is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly any one overload of `object_t::foo` must have a single return type, and for good reason: if a client could receive an object of a type that only exists in some other translation unit that creates an `object_t`, how could the compiler possibly generate code to handle that?  If there were some type into which all the various return types could be converted, you could use that as the outer return type, but that’s surely too limiting.

You could, of course, provide a `foo` function *template* that at least *accepted* any type, but how would you implement it?  Function templates cannot be `virtual`, for the similar reason that the size of the (typical) vtable could not be known from any one translation unit.  You can route each of several known types to its own virtual function, but the list of such functions must be known in advance; alternatively, you can again rely on converting any argument to some known type, but the client of the template could just do that themselves.

The only other choice is to define an *interface* for the argument and return value to provide and write all implementation classes and client code against it.  That is of course how many scripting languages work: in essence, each built-in function in CPython has the signature

```
PyObject* func(PyObject*);
```

and thus even a stateful C++-accessible manipulator of arbitrary Python data could be stored in a `std::function<PyObject*(PyObject*)>` without defining your own type-erased class.